# Using NSLayoutConstraint on UITextView resets contentSize to {0,0}

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, autolayout

I have a `UITextView` on which I am using an `NSLayoutConstraint` to dodge the keyboard. Here's the constraint:

```
self.textViewBottomConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:textView
                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                       toItem:self.view
                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                   multiplier:1.0
                                                     constant:0.0];
[self.view addConstraint:self.textViewBottomConstraint];
```

When the keyboard shows/hides I animate the constraint by setting the constraint constant to the keyboard height. However, doing so for some reason resets the contentSize to {0,0}, thus breaking scrolling. I've added a hack to `handleKeyboardDidHide:` to reset the contentSize to what it was before being reset, but this has some ugly side effects such as the scroll position being reset and the view not scrolling to the cursor position until typing starts.

```
- (void) handleKeyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
     CGFloat height = [KeyboardObserver sharedInstance].keyboardFrame.size.height;
     self.textView.constant = -height;
     [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}

- (void) handleKeyboardDidHide:(NSNotification *)notification
{
   // for some reason, setting the bottom constraint resets the contentSize to {0,0}...
   // so let's save it before and reset it after.
   // HACK
   CGSize size = self.textView.contentSize;
   self.textView.constant = 0.0;
   [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
   self.textView.contentSize = size;
}
```

Anyone know how to avoid this issue altogether?

Comment: It sounds like maybe you have a constraint from the top to the top of the superview as well. If so, you want to get rid of it, but have an explicit height set for the text view instead.

Comment: @rdelmar Why would a top constraint matter or affect contentSize in any way? In any case, removing the top constraint would mean throwing out autolayout altogether for this viewcontroller.

Comment: Because if you have a top constraint, and you move the bottom up to where the top is, then the only way to satisfy the constraints is to have 0 height.

Comment: @rdelmar The bottom is being moved by the height of the keyboard -- not to the top of the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what's wrong with your code, and we can deal with that in detail if you want. But as an initial suggestion, if possible, don't resize the UITextView: just change its content and scroll insets, like this:

```
- (void) keyboardShow: (NSNotification*) n {
    NSDictionary* d = [n userInfo];
    CGRect r = [d[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    self.tv.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,r.size.height,0);
    self.tv.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,r.size.height,0);
}
```

Even so, I find that you have to wait until the keyboard hide animation completes before resetting those values:

```
- (void) keyboardHide: (NSNotification*) n {
    NSDictionary* d = [n userInfo];
    NSNumber* curve = d[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey];
    NSNumber* duration = d[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration.floatValue delay:0
                        options:curve.integerValue << 16
                     animations:
     ^{
         [self.tv setContentOffset:CGPointZero];
     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
         self.tv.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
         self.tv.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
     }];
}
```

(It may be that that trick would help your code somehow as well.)